# Функция split для C

Tags: c, arduino

Есть тип данных **char** который содержит следующий текст:

```
+CMT: "+79643437397","","15/06/09,17:34:01+12"
1+ON+60
```

Он начинается с **\r\n**, но здесь это не отобразить, поскольку в буфере откуда это получается могут быть и другие данные то требуется разбить это по \r\n и проверить длину, если длина составляет 3 строки, то дальше уже последнюю строку надо разбить по плюсу, на JS я бы сделал это так:

```
var a = "
+CMT: "+79643437397","","15/06/09,17:34:01+12"
1+ON+60
";
var b = a.split("/r/n");
if (b.length == 3) {
    var c = b[2].split("+");
    if (c.length == 3) {
        // Выполнение функции по полученным данным из c ({1, "ON", 60})
    }
}
```

Но с **C** я работаю первый раз, решил запустить пример который нашел в интернете:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h> 

char str[] = "John|Doe|Melbourne|6270|AU";
char *fname, *lname;
char *oldstr = malloc(sizeof(str));
strcpy(oldstr,str);         
fname=strtok(str,"|");
lname=strtok(NULL,"|");
printf("Firstname: %s\n", fname);
printf("Lastname: %s\n", lname);
free(oldstr);
```

но и тут все на так гладко, библиотеки malloc.h вообще не оказалось в среде разработки Arduino, скачал эту - http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.h , но думаю в ней явно что-то не так, в итоге ошибка:

```
Blink.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Blink:27: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Вот что находится на 27 строке:

```
char *oldstr = malloc(sizeof(str));
```

В итоге совсем не знаю что со всем этим делать, помогите примером

Comment: `char *oldstr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(str));`

Comment: @klopp: Это с чего это вдруг?

Comment: @GeneralProger: Ваши ошибки компиляции лезут в первую очередь из-за того, что вы компилируете этот С код как С++ код. Тем не мнее в тэге здесь вы почему-то поставили [C]. Вы уж определитесь, какой язык вы пытаетесь использовать - С или С++. С и С++ - два совершенно разных языка.

Comment: @AnT, у arduino с C свои заморочки, и свои компиляторы.

Comment: @klopp: Именно такой заморочки (запрет на конверсию `void *` в `char *`) у Arduino в С нет.

Comment: На самом же деле Вам достаточно убедиться (один проход по строке), что у Вас 2 символа `'\n'` (можно при этом запомнить позицию (или адрес) последнего) и найти `+` после этого `\n` (в общем-то тоже можно сделать в этом единственном цикле).

Answer (score 2):

Я уже написал в комментарии, что для описанной Вами задачки никакой split() не нужен.

Попробуйте (без malloc, обработка по месту исходных данных)

```
// Возвращаем позицию первого плюса в 3-ей строке или 0 (нет плюса или не 3 строки
// по указателю nlpos вернем позицию последнего \n в str[]
int 
plpos (const char *str, int *nlpos) 
{
  int nl = 0, plpos = 0, i;

  for (*nlpos = -1, i = 0; str[i]; i++) 
    if (str[i] == '\n') {
      nl++;
      plpos = 0;
      *nlpos = i;
    } else if (str[i] == '+' && !plpos)
      plpos = i;

  return nl == 2 ? plpos : 0;
}
```

и где-то в Вашей программе:

```
int nlpos, ppos = plpos(my_str, &nlpos);
if (ppos) {
   char *str3 = my_str + nlpos + 1;
   // тут обрабатываете свою 3-ю строку  (str3)
   int str3ppos = ppos - nlpos - 1; // это позиция первого плюса "в координатах" str3
   ...
}
```

Если же данные, начиная с str3 на самом деле *должны быть копией*, то напишите:

```
....
   char str3 = strdup(my_str + nlpos + 1);
....
```

В этом случае функция strdup (надеюсь она есть в arduino) сделает malloc (тогда не забудьте free).